$\sum 2^{-r_n}/r_n$ diverges $\implies$ $\sum 2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil} / {\lceil r_n \rceil}$ diverges
I want to prove $\sum 2^{-r_n}/r_n$ diverges $\implies$ $\sum 2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil} / {\lceil r_n \rceil}$ diverges where $r_n$ is a nondecreasing sequence of reals. This came up in Billingsley Probability and Measure Example 4.15. $r_n$ is a nondecreasing sequence. It is not stated in the example that $r_n$ are positive but it references an earlier example in which the $r_n$ are positive so you can assume $r_n$ are positive reals if that helps. I tried using the comparison test to prove this but it doesn't work because the inequality is the wrong way around i.e.  $\sum 2^{-r_n}/r_n \geq \sum 2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil} / {\lceil r_n \rceil}$
EDIT: You can assume there is an integer $N$ such that $r_n>1$ if $n\geq N$.

Hint:
The ceiling function $\lceil \cdot \rceil: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\lceil x \rceil = \min{k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid k \geq x}$. For any $r_n \in \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $r_n \leq \lceil r_n \rceil$, and since $\lceil r_n \rceil - 1 < r_n \leq \lceil r_n \rceil$, we have $\lceil r_n \rceil < r_n + 1$, thus establishing that $r_n \leq \lceil r_n \rceil < r_n + 1$.

I tried something like this you get $2^{-\lceil r_n\rceil} > (1/2) 2^{-r_n}$ but you still can't apply the comparison test because $1/r_n \geq 1/{\lceil r_n \rceil}$ and more work is needed.

For example it is not obvious to me that $\sum 2^{-r_n}/({r_n+1})$ would diverge since these terms are strictly smaller.

Observe that $$ \lceil r_n \rceil \leq r_n + 1 \implies \frac{1}{\lceil r_n \rceil} \geq \frac{1}{r_n + 1}. $$$$ \lceil r_n \rceil \leq r_n+1 \implies 2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil} \geq 2^{-(r_n + 1)} = \frac{2^{-r_n}}{2}. $$ Gives $$ \frac{2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil}}{\lceil r_n \rceil} \geq \frac{\frac{2^{-r_n}}{2}}{r_n+1} = \frac{2^{-r_n}}{2(r_n + 1)}. $$ Since $\sum \frac{2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil}}{\lceil r_n \rceil}$ dominate $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-r_n}}{2(r_n + 1)}$ $$ \sum \frac{2^{-r_n}}{r_n} \text{ diverges} \implies \sum \frac{2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil}}{\lceil r_n \rceil} \text{ diverges}.$$

I see that if $\sum 2^{-r_n}/(r_n+1)$ diverges then $\sum 2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil}/{\lceil r_n \rceil}$ diverges but I don't see why $\sum 2^{-r_n}/(r_n+1)$ diverges.

Oh! You are right. If $r_n >1$ then $r_n > \frac{r_n +1}{2}$ gives $\frac{1}{r_n} < \frac{2}{r_n+1}.$ Hence $\frac{2^{-r_n}}{r_n} \leq 2 \cdot \frac{2^{-r_n}}{2(r_n + 1)} = \frac{2^{-r_n}}{r_n + 1}$ Since $\sum \frac{2^{-r_n}}{r_n}$ diverges, then $\sum \frac{2^{-r_n}}{r_n + 1}$ diverges.

I think this could work. Looking at the example I think we can assume that $r_n>1$ for large enough $n$ i.e $r_n>1$ if $n\geq N$. Because if $r_n \leq 1$ for arbitrarily large $n$ then what he is trying to prove in Example 4.15 which is equation 4.25 holds by Equation 4.24 if $r_n \leq 1$ for arbitrarily large $n$. Too many details to spell out in comments but I think we can assume $r_n >1$ if $n\geq N$.

Yeah it works. If you want to write it up in an answer I will be happy to accept. If $n\geq N$ then $2^{-r_n}/r_n \leq 2 \cdot 2^{-r_n}/(r_n+1)$ so by comparison test $\sum 2^{-r_n}/(r_n+1)$ diverges and since $(1/2) 2^{-r_n}/(r_n+1)\leq 2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil}/{\lceil r_n \rceil}$ it follows by the comparison test that $\sum 2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil}/{\lceil r_n \rceil}$ diverges.

The ceiling function $ \lceil \cdot \rceil: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} $ is defined by $ \lceil x \rceil = \min \{ k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid k \geq x \} $. For any $ r_n \in \mathbb{R} $, it holds that $ r_n \leq \lceil r_n \rceil $. Since $ \lceil r_n \rceil - 1 < r_n \leq \lceil r_n \rceil $, we have $ \lceil r_n \rceil < r_n + 1 $. Thus, we can establish that:
$$
r_n \leq \lceil r_n \rceil < r_n + 1
$$
Now, observe:
$$
\lceil r_n \rceil \leq r_n + 1 \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{\lceil r_n \rceil} \geq \frac{1}{r_n + 1}
$$
$$
\lceil r_n \rceil \leq r_n + 1 \Longrightarrow 2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil} \geq 2^{-(r_n + 1)} = \frac{2^{-r_n}}{2}
$$
So, we get:
$$
\frac{2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil}}{\lceil r_n \rceil} \geq \frac{\frac{2^{-r_n}}{2}}{r_n + 1} = \frac{2^{-r_n}}{2(r_n + 1)}
$$
Now, assume $ r_n > 1 $ for sufficiently large $ n $. For $ r_n > 1 $, note that:
$$
r_n > \frac{r_n + 1}{2} \implies \frac{1}{r_n} < \frac{2}{r_n + 1}
$$
Hence, we have:
$$
\frac{2^{-r_n}}{r_n} \leq 2 \cdot \frac{2^{-r_n}}{2(r_n + 1)} = \frac{2^{-r_n}}{r_n + 1}
$$
Given the divergence of $ \sum \frac{2^{-r_n}}{r_n} $, the series $ \sum \frac{2^{-r_n}}{r_n + 1} $ must also diverge by the comparison test. We have also shown that:
$$
\frac{2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil}}{\lceil r_n \rceil} \geq \frac{2^{-r_n}}{2(r_n + 1)}
$$
Thus, if $ \sum \frac{2^{-r_n}}{r_n} $ diverges, then $ \sum \frac{2^{-\lceil r_n \rceil}}{\lceil r_n \rceil} $ must also diverge by the comparison test.

The part $2^{-r_n}/r_n\leq 2^{-r_n}/(r_n+1)$ is false. Don't know how reviewers think this is a true statement. I edited the answer to correct this but it has changed again. But it doesn't matter. You just need to show $2^{-r_n}/r_n \leq 2 \cdot 2^{-r_n}/{(r_n+1)}$.
